# Why the strange behavior of the test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I trying to unit-test my app, and I write this

```
    it 'with checkbox' do
      @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
      expect{ @order }.to change{ Client.count }.by(1)
    end
```

and shell show me an error

```
   expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

but why? I was binding spec via `pry` and make this:
before `@order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)` I call

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Order::CreateAValidOrder>)> Client.count
=> 0
```

after `@order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)` I call

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Order::CreateAValidOrder>)> Client.count
=> 1
```

it works, but why rspec show me an error? I do not understand

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

I think `@order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)` is being executed before the expect command. Please try below code:

```
it 'with checkbox' do
    expect{ FactoryGirl.create(:order) }.to change{ Client.count }.by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

@order is set after you have created the record in the database.   So, in fact, it's value has not changed.

You're better off going in this direction:

expect { FactoryGirl.create(:order) }.to change(Order, :count).by(1)